# What is a metahuman?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash, legends-of-tomorrow

While doing a rewatch of DC’s Legends of Tomorrow, I watched Season 3: Episode 3, titled “Zari.”

In the episode, the Legends travel to a future where ARGUS has outlawed metahumans.  After being cornered by an evil drone, it refers to Sara Lance (White Canary), Ray Palmer (Atom), and Mick Rory (Heat Wave) as metahumans.

I was under the impression that the Flash defined metahumans as people who were affected by the Particle Accelerator or something similar.  Aren’t those three Legends just ordinary humans?  Am I wrong about metahumans?  What is a metahuman?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the D.C. universe they seem to use the word Metahuman instead of Mutant (like the Marvel Universe. The term "metahuman" seems to vary as well. Often times they refer to aliens (like Superman) as having "meta" abilities.  However to answer the other part of your question, Sara Lance (White Canary), Ray Palmer (Atom), and Mick Rory (Heat Wave) are not metahumans because none of them actually have powers. All there abilities come from technology.  Unlike the Marvel universe where many of there heroes are mutants (born with powers), The D.C. universe seems to use mutates (people who gain powers from accidents,etc..like spiderman) In The Flash, nearly every hero and bad guy that appears in that show seems to have been mutated by the particle accelerator accident and gained metahuman abilities. In the comics alot of these people got there powers in many different ways.